# Best Blackberry Dev environment

Tags: java, blackberry

What development environments do most BB devs use out there?  I haven't programmed much Java in 6-7 years and typically used NetBeans or JCreator for projects as I found Eclipse cumbersome.  RIM has the plugin for Eclipse, but I've also read some posts where people are using whatever editor they want and then using ANT for builds and testing.

I'm coming from .NET so obviously I'm a heavy VS.NET user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your supported options are JDE (simply not very capable compared to any modern IDE), and Eclipse. For widget development, the VIsual Studio plugin supports VS 2005 and 2008 (I don't think 2010 is yet, but I expect it won't be far behind.)

I've gone through great pains trying to stick with Netbeans (Eclipse makes me itch), but eventually had to give up and switch to Eclipse.  The support simply isn't there; I was able to get the basic debugging to work with Netbeans, but that was just about it.  Simple things like "break on uncaught exception"; or localization handling (if using string resources) were either not possible, or very inefficient.

The JDE is adequate for debugging, if only barely.  However in my experience (especially in the very latest versions) there's no difference at all between the JDE and Eclipse debugging features.

The other option you have is to use the IDE of your choice; and ant-based build scripts.  That would let you use .  You will still have some pain points (mostly localization handling), but it would do the job. The Blackberry Ant Tools project can be found here: http://bb-ant-tools.sourceforge.net/docs.  In this case you would still want to use JDE/Eclipse for ease of debugging, but would be able to do most of your development in the IDE of your choice.

Comment: Agreed.  I have used IntelliJ Idea for so long I just can't get myself to make the switch to Eclipse, so I end up using Idea to create and edit code, JDE to compile and run in simulator (and for debugging), and bb-ant-tools for packaging and deployment.  However, now that RIM has devoted most of their tools resources to Eclipse I can see more and more of a pull to that environment every year...

Comment: JDE is horrid beyond words.. Stick to the eclipse bb plugin like Marc said.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using both RIM tools. Eclipse plugin is good for development and now even supports hot-swap debugging on the Simulator.
But if you need on device debugging and logging - for me, only JDE worked correctly, so I keep both these tools in my toolbelt :)

If you want to try the ANT route, it's possible, for example look at Wordpress BB application, it shows a good way of working with BB project and ANT. IntelliJ handles it pretty well.

Answer (score -2):

There are a number of specific free development environments provided by RIM, and which you can download, including an Eclipse plugin.

Comment: I wouldn't say "a number" of them.  RIM provides two java development environments, the JDE and the Eclipse plugin.  And if you'd read the user's question you'd see that he already knew that and was asking what people's preference was.

Comment: The question only mentions the Eclipse plugin, not the JDE, so I have no reason to think he knows about it. And he says "what environments do people use" not "what is your preference".